# How could I download a file like .doc or .pdf from internet to my harddrive using  c#

Tags: c#

How could I download a  file like .doc , .pdf from internet to my
hard drive using  c#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile( "url", "localFilename");
}
```

Comment: can i use FTP to search files like .doc .pdf

Comment: @araf: that is a totally different problem you are describing - do you want to *download* a file or *search* for files?

Comment: You can use FTP to download (just use a "ftp://..." url) but AFAIK you cannot search using the WebClient.

Comment: @araf: _How_ do you want to download them? What starting info do you have? Try to be clearer in your questions.

Answer (score 3):

use the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class:

```
using(WebClient wc = new WebClient())
wc.DownloadFile("http://a.com/foo.pdf", @"D:\foo.pdf");
```

**Edit based on comments:**

Based on your comments *I think* what you are trying to do is download i.e. PDF files that are linked to from an HTML page. In that case you can

1. Download the page (with WebClient,
   see above)
2. Use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to find
   all the links within the page that
   point to pdf files
3. Download the pdf files

> i am developing a crawler were if i
>   specify a keyword for eg:SHA algorithm
>   and i select the option .pdf or .doc
>   from the crawler it should download
>   the file with selected format in to a
>   targeted folder ..

Based on your clarification this is a solution using google to get the results of the search:

```
DownloadSearchHits("SHA", "pdf");

...

public static void DownloadSearchHits(string searchTerm, string fileType)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string html = wc.DownloadString(string.Format("http://www.google.com/search?q={0}+filetype%3A{1}", searchTerm, fileType));
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);
        var pdfLinks = doc.DocumentNode
                            .SelectNodes("//a")
                            .Where(link => link.Attributes["href"] != null 
                                   && link.Attributes["href"].Value.EndsWith(".pdf"))
                            .Select(link => link.Attributes["href"].Value)
                            .ToList();

        int index = 0;
        foreach (string pdfUrl in pdfLinks)
        {
            wc.DownloadFile(pdfUrl, 
                            string.Format(@"C:\download\{0}.{1}", 
                                            index++, 
                                            fileType));
        }
    }
}
```

In general though you should ask a question related to **a particular problem you have with a given implementation that you already have** - based on your question you are very far off being able to implement a standalone crawler.

Comment: @araf: you have to specify the URL you want to download the file from and the local file you want to save it to.

Answer (score 3):

The most simple way is use [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx)

Comment: @araf: If you seriously want to discus/ask that then give an example of the url, at least.

Answer (score 1):

Use [WebClient.DownloadFile()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) from System.Net

Answer (score 0):

Using WebClient.DownloadFile

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx

```
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = client.DownloadFile(url, filename);
    }
```